# What is the use of 'all' in Magento 2.3 Rest API URLs?

Tags: magento2, rest-api

To get the customer token, the following URL works.

```
https://localhost/magento/rest/V1/integration/customer/token
```

But the following URL do not.

```
https://localhost/magento/rest/all/V1/integration/customer/token
```

I have seen this 'all' used in other API URLs as well. What is the use of it?

Answer (score 0):

[Magnto Dev doc](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/generate-local.html)

> all. This value only applies to the CMS and Product modules. If this
>   value is specified, the API call affects all the merchant’s stores.
>
> To return the complete JSON schema, specify the ?services=all
>   parameter in the URL. The default store_code is all, but you can also
>   specify default or a store code defined on the system. For example:
>   http:///rest/default/schema?services=all

Comment: What if we don't pass 'all' or 'default' code? Will it take default store?

Comment: @piyush_systematix check updated answer.

Comment: Which store code is used for the API https://localhost/magento/rest/V1/integration/customer/token ?

Comment: please upvote if it give answer of main question

Comment: I am still looking for answer. I understood that we can pass store code but I still need to know what happens when we don't add anything like in the URL I shared in my previous comment.